# Python: Add or remove timezone hours from a timestamp and get actual time

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, datetime, python-datetime

In Python, I need to get the actual time of a given string timestamp converted to a different timezone without timezone information. I am using pytz to do this. But all I get is the given DateTime with the timezone information appended to it.

Base datetime : **2020-05-29 19:00:00** (A string datetime without timezone info)

Requirement: When this time is converted to **(US Zipcode 90071) -0700** timezone,
it should return "**2020-05-29 12:00:00**", not "**2020-05-29 19:00:00-0700**"

Code:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
from uszipcode import SearchEngine
from timezonefinder import TimezoneFinder

date_time_obj = datetime.strptime("2020-05-29 19:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
zip = "90071"

search = SearchEngine(simple_zipcode=True)
zipcode = search.by_zipcode(zip)
zipcode = zipcode.to_dict()
tf = TimezoneFinder(in_memory=True)
timezone = tf.timezone_at(lng=zipcode['lng'], lat=zipcode['lat'])
tz = pytz.timezone(timezone)
new_timestamp = tz.localize(date_time_obj)

new_timestamp_str = datetime.strftime(new_timestamp, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

But this returns **2020-05-29 19:00:00.000000-0700**. I need to retrieve a DateTime object/string with the actual time shown in that timezone without a timezone chunk attached to the end of the DateTime.

Comment: Wait, how are you converting the `datetime` to a string?  That part is missing from the code you posted.

Comment: @MarkRansom updated the question with that part,

Comment: I don't understand, I wouldn't expect `strftime` to include a time zone if the format didn't specify it.

Comment: @MarkRansom all I need is to minus 0700 from 2020-05-29 19:00:00 and get 2020-05-29 12:00:00. Either as a DateTime object or a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your "Base datetime" refers to UTC, you have to add a `tzinfo=UTC` first ***before*** you convert to another timezone. Also, avoid overwriting built-ins like `zip`. Example using `dateutil`:

```
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil
from uszipcode import SearchEngine
from timezonefinder import TimezoneFinder

date_time_obj = datetime.strptime("2020-05-29 19:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
zipcode = "90071"

search = SearchEngine(simple_zipcode=True)
zipcode = search.by_zipcode(zipcode)
zipcode = zipcode.to_dict()
tf = TimezoneFinder(in_memory=True)
timezone = tf.timezone_at(lng=zipcode['lng'], lat=zipcode['lat'])

# localize to UTC first
date_time_obj = date_time_obj.replace(tzinfo=dateutil.tz.UTC)

# now localize to timezone of the zipcode:
new_timestamp = date_time_obj.astimezone(dateutil.tz.gettz(timezone))

new_timestamp_str = datetime.strftime(new_timestamp, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
# '05/29/2020 12:00:00'
```

If you need to use `pytz`, make sure to use `localize` instead of `replace` (even though UTC is an exception).

Sidenote: If your "Base datetime" refers to *local time* (operating system), you could obtain that timezone by

```
import time
import dateutil
localtzname = time.tzname[time.daylight]
tz = dateutil.tz.gettz(localtzname)
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. It is using the server time not the PC time.

Comment: @TechyTee: ok great, that should hopefully be UTC :)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your original date and time are in UTC.  So for `localize` to work properly, you have to start with the proper timezone attached.

```
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime("2020-05-29 19:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
```

Then you can remove it again after the conversion:

```
return date_time_obj.astimezone(tz).replace(tzinfo=None)
```

Comment: No this doesn't work. It still gives "2020-05-29 19:00:00"

Comment: @TechyTee sorry, this is a new PC that doesn't have pytz installed yet so I wasn't able to try it.  But it should have worked!

Comment: @TechyTee I installed pytz and tried my original answer, it didn't work at all - produced an error!  I've updated it, see if it works now.